# get active number page in DataPager

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms, datapager

i have LinkButton inside ListView control, i want get active number page in DataPager with click on LinkButton.

```
protected void addToCart_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get active number page
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do something like the following assuming that you are doing this in `asp.net`

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender,PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)    
{
    int currPage = (e.StartRowIndex / e.MaximumRows)+1;
    Response.Write(currPage.ToString());
}
```

Comment: thx. please help me for and set active number page in dataPager